# Is it possible to append a selected value from angular dropdown to gluu url?

Tags: angular, url, append, dropdown, gluu

Currently i am working on angular as a beginner and my task is to append selected value from dropdown to gluu login page url like this

If my Url is like this before append
**strong text**
**http://localhost/folder/Home**

after append the url will be
**http://something/xyz.passless.xhtml**

my question is how to append value like this when i will click on signin button the url should be like this
[click this link to see he image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUBad.png)
**http://something/xyz.passless.xhtml?lang=en**

suppose my dropdown is like this

```
<select>
<option value=en>en</option>
<option value=en>fr</option>
</select>
```

plz help me and give a good solution of this problem
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Handle on change event in Html

```html
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
<option value=en>en</option>
<option value=fr>fr</option>
</select>
```

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){}

// Navigate to the url with params
onChange(currentVal) {
    // suppose your current url is http://something/xyz.passless.xhtml
    // after navigation url will be http://something/xyz.passless.xhtml?lang=en
    this.router.navigate([`/xyz.passless.xhtml`], {
         queryParams: {
              lang: currentVal // 'en' --add any number of params
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Kindly correct your answer the path provided in navigate method is invalid, Based on op's question it looks like an external link either use document.location or window.href

Comment: I'm assuming AnilKumar wants only to `update navigation url bar`. Using `docment.location` will reload the page. Feel free to edit and correct mistakes

Comment: Thank you so much let me try i will let u know if it will work

Comment: yeah ur solution is purely correct but the problem is  that my current url is http://localhost:8100/folder/Home

Comment: **url is**=[link]localhost:8100/folder/Home

Comment: and after selectig value from dropdown when i am clicking on the signin button the selected value should be appended in the gluu url

Comment: before appended in localhost:folder/home  after  appended gluu url something/passless.xhtml?lang=en

Comment: I didn't quite get, could you elaborate

Comment: yeah i have updated my post u can check my existing queston i have updated it

Comment: my problem is i have a home  page on this location  localhost:folder/Home i want the selected value from dropdown list from this page to gluu url when i will click on sign in button

Comment: dropdown button and signin button are in same page when i will s elect any language like english tt's value shoulld be appended with the gluu url when i will click on sign in buttn

Comment: suppose my gluu url is like this http://somehing/passless.xhtml

Comment: i want the value should be appended like this http://something/passless.xhtml?lang=en

Comment: 1.select value from dropdown,2.click on signn button,3.value will be appended to gluu url     thats it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUBad.png      visit this link to get more clarity on problem